# How to apply filter

Tags: php, filters, excerpt

I want my excerpt to be shorter than the default 55 characters. So I found this code in the Wordpress [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/):

```
/**
 * Filter the except length to 20 words.
 *
 * @param int $length Excerpt length.
 * @return int (Maybe) modified excerpt length.
 */
function wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

How do I apply this filter to my code, which looks like this:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the code inside `functions.php` that lives in your theme folder:

```
wp-content/themes/[your-active-theme-name]/functions.php
```

Comment: Okay I did that and it does not seem to have any effect. Even if I change the 999 to 20, the pursue of which I'm not sure about. I presume its the argument $lenght, but even if it is, I don't see how it is being used inside the function wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length